# Proper way to use universal quantification with multiple arguments

Tags: logic, notation

Which one is correct?

$\forall x \in X, y \in Y:$ some expression

or

$\forall x \in X \wedge y \in Y:$ some expression

or

$\forall x \in X \forall y \in Y:$ some expression

Comment: The first is ambiguous, the second is plain wrong, the third is clear.

Comment: @user710587: The first is generally not ambiguous; it can become so if used carelessly.

Comment: Agreed @BrianM.Scott. I was trying to help in finding the best answer. If I'm not working with beginners I opt for the first as well.

Comment: @user710587: Fair enough.

Comment: Why is the second one inherently wrong?

Comment: Because "$\forall$" is used with an element, followed by a set. This is not the case here.  If you wish, something like "$\forall (x,y) \in X \times Y$," would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall x\in X,y\in Y\big(\varphi(x,y)\big)$ is acceptable, but you do have to be extra careful to put brackets of some sort around the expression in order to make it clear that $y\in Y$ is part of the quantifier, not something within the scope of $\forall x\in X$. Your second version is meaningless: it’s simply not well-formed even informally. The standard, unexceptionable form is $$\forall x\in X\,\forall y\in Y\big(\varphi(x,y)\big)\;.$$

Comment: Perhaps $(\forall x\in X)(\forall y\in Y)\varphi(x,y)$ would look OK.

Comment: At some point, I have to use something like this:

$\forall x \in X, \forall y_i, y_j \in Y :$ ...

therefore the first solution seems a bit problematic. Would 
$(\forall x \in X), (\forall y_i, y_j \in Y )$ be apropriate?

Comment: @André: Yes, that works fine too. For some reason I’ve never cared much for that style, so I tend to forget about it.

Comment: @michalm: Yes, that’s okay.